# How to use the PostgreSQL pgp_sym_encrypt / decrypt function to encrypt data used in the Like command of the WHERE clause of the SQL DELETE statement?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I need to perform a delete operation on a PostgreSQL database, where the text fields involved were encrypted using the pgp_sym_encrypt() function. I'm trying to make the comparison in the Like command using pgp_sym_encrypt in the string, so that it matches the content of the field that is stored in the database, but I'm not having success.

Below is one of the attempts I made to use the encrypted value of a text as a condition of the DELETE statement.

DELETE from estado WHERE nome LIKE ( pgp_*sym*_encrypt('Rio', AbcdAbcdAbcdAbcd',  'cipher-algo=aes192')::text;

Casting to text, I succeed but I don't have any lines affected by the statement, but I'm sure at least one record in the database in the field name has the value 'Rio'.

[enter image description her](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6eT5.jpg)Query with Rio in result

I really don't know how I should change the SQL statement to be able to delete all the records that meet the requirement. I thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The default encryption method uses a salt, so every encryption of the same value will give a different result.  See s2k-mode in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html), but of course that can't help you if the data is already stored with salts.

Since you apparently already know the right way to do it based on your image-of-text, why are you trying to do it the wrong way instead?

Comment: Thank you, jjanes. If possible, could you help me understand s2k-mode better? To test it, I deleted all the records in my test base and made an insertion with the following instruction: insert into estado (nome) values 
(pgp_sym_encrypt('Rio', 'AbcdAbcdAbcdAbcd', 's2k-mode=1' ));  But when deleting with the following instruction I also had no success: delete from estado where estado.nome like 
(pgp_sym_encrypt('Rio', 'AbcdAbcdAbcdAbcd', 's2k-mode=1' ))::text